# Graph the region of a two variable inequation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

I need help with $( x + y -1) ( x - y +1) y <= 0$

There is a known method to conclude what area of the XY plane satisfy that inequation?.

I usually have the same problem with other inequations of two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break up the inequality into two cases: the product is zero, and the product is negative.

If $(x - y - 1)(x - y + 1)y = 0$, then at least one of them is zero.

If $(x + y - 1)(x - y + 1)y < 0$, then none of the terms in the product is zero, so each one is either positive or negative. Now

- if all three were positive, then the product would be positive;
- if two were positive, and one negative, the product would be negative;
- if one was positive, and two negative, the product would be positive;
- if all three were negative, then the product would be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Divide the xy plane into regions using the lines $y=0,~ x+y-1=0$, and $x-y+1=0$. Now look at where each of these functions is positive and negative. If exactly three or exactly one of them is negative in some region, then that region satisfies your inequality. The final answer will be the union of all such regions.